# Replace integers with labels across different columns - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda data frame with several column of integers, as well as a corresponding dictionary of {column : {integer:string_label}}.

I am trying to create a dataframe in which the integers have been replaced by their labels. The closest I got is below, but the output is somewhat unexpected.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,3,8],'b':[8,8,8,8,7]})

dic = {'a':{1:"label1",2:"label2",3:"label3"}, 'b':{8:'label8',7:'label7'}}


converters = {column: lambda x: dic[column][x] if x in dic[column].keys() else np.nan for column in dic.keys()}

new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({col: series.apply(converters[col]) 
                            if col in converters else series
                            for col, series in df.iteritems()})
print new

#Output:
#         a       b
# 0     NaN  label8
# 1     NaN  label8
# 2     NaN  label8
# 3     NaN  label8
# 4  label8  label7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 3, 8], 'b': [8, 8, 8, 8, 7]})

dic = {'a': {1: "label1", 2: "label2", 3: "label3"},
       'b': {8: 'label8', 7: 'label7'}}

df = df.replace(dic)

allowed = {k: v.values() for k, v in dic.items()}

for col_name, allowed_col_vals in allowed.items():
    # Let's replace not allowed values by NaN
    df[col_name][~df[col_name].isin(allowed_col_vals)] = np.nan
```

The `df` ends up like this:

```
        a       b
0  label1  label8
1  label2  label8
2  label3  label8
3  label3  label8
4     NaN  label7
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the variable `column` inside the lambda function, the lambda declaration won't store the value, it will use what the variable holds at the time it is being called ( in `series.apply(converters[col])`), and it can be anything. In fact, if you run your code some times you will notice that it gives different results.

A possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,3,8],'b':[8,8,8,8,7]})


dic = {'a':{1:"label1",2:"label2",3:"label3"}, 'b':{8:'label8',7:'label7'}}


new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({col: series.apply(lambda x: dic[col][x] if x in dic[col].keys() else np.nan)
                             if col in dic.keys() else series
                             for col, series in df.iteritems()})
print(new)
```